# Unable to get data with RETROFIT + COROUTINE

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to make a simple network call with Retrofit and doing it asynchronously with coroutines, but when I run the app, there is absolutely no response. No information. I can't tell if the call is being made. Please help.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MainActivity"
    var job: Job? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://howtodoandroid.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitService::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.getAllMovies()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val movies = response.body()
                if (movies != null) {
                    for (movie in movies) {
                        Log.d(TAG, movie.name)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

}

interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("movielist.json")
    suspend fun getAllMovies() : Response<List<Movie>>
}

data class Movie(val name: String, val imageUrl: String, val category: String)
```

Comment: Do you have the internet permission added in the manifest?

Comment: can you also post `RetrofitService` interface? Have you checked logs?

Comment: including the permissions and `RetrofitService`, could you also see if there are any log output when doing the request?

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest you to return `Call` instead of `Response` from `getAllMovies()` then call `execute()` on it.

The resulting code will look like:

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("movielist.json")
    suspend fun getAllMovies() : Call<List<Movie>>
}
```

and

```
val response = api.getAllMovies().execute()
```

This should work.